# Nativescript Android intellisense when using typescript

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

Is there any d.ts or nativescript plugin file for code completion/intellisense of the android API when using typescript? I think it should be more or less "easy" possible to generate one from the android docs but I would like to avoid to do that myself if possible.

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/declarations.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is coming in the next version (1.8) and iOS/Android d.ts files will be available for download via npm/tsd.

In the mean time you can just download the declarations from the NativeScript repo and add the files to your project.

For Android you need:

- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/release/android17.d.ts
- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/release/declarations.android.d.ts

For iOS you need:

- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/release/ios.d.ts
- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/release/declarations.ios.d.ts